# Encode source mjpeg with variable framerate using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I set my old smartphone to be a "cctv" cam. The stream is MJPEG.

When I capture with ffmpeg using this command:

`ffmpeg -y -f mjpeg -i http://192.168.1.3:8080/video -c:v libx264 -an cam.mp4`

I get a faster playback.

I've already tried `-vsync vfr`, `-framerate` increasing and decreasing the rate. Nothing works. Always fast playback (like ~ 2x)

When I play using `ffplay http://192.168.1.3:8080/video` the playback speed is perfect.

What is the ffmpeg commands to encode the video properly with the source having a variable bitrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A raw stream won't convey a framerate to ffmpeg, so a default of 25 is used. Instead, do

```
ffmpeg -y -f mjpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i http://192.168.1.3:8080/video -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vsync 0 -c:v libx264 -an cam.mp4
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked just as expected. Thanks!